# Programming error: Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list' while connecting to MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write data from a .csv file into a MySQL database. While running my code, I get the following output: **mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'**

```
add_sql = ("INSERT INTO db "
           "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")

def data_processor():
    df = (pandas.read_csv('data.csv').T)
    i = 0
    while i < (len(df.T['id'])):
        id = df[i]['id']
        name = df[i]['name']
        desc = df[i]['desc']
        link = df[i]['link']
        output = (id, name, desc, link)
        cursor.execute(add_sql, output)
        i = i + 1

data_processor()
```

I'm new to programming and really have no clue what could be causing this. When I enter the data manually into the add_sql string it works, so the problem must be with the data_processor function?

My python and mysql are up to date. I've done plenty of googling, searching here on stackoverflow and tried to make different changes in my code but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated :3

Sample of the output variable, which I'm trying to write into the database.

```
(38, 'The legacy Iterator protocol', 'Firefox, prior to version 26 implemented another iterator protocol that is similar to the standard <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/The_Iterator_protocol">ES2015 Iterator protocol</a>.', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features/The_legacy_Iterator_protocol')
(39, 'Expressions and operators', 'This chapter documents all the JavaScript language operators, expressions and keywords.', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators')
(40, 'Arithmetic operators', '<strong>Arithmetic operators</strong> take numerical values (either literals or variables) as their operands and return a single numerical value. The standard arithmetic operators are addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*), and division (/).', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators')
(41, 'Array comprehensions', 'The <strong>array comprehension</strong> syntax was a JavaScript expression which allowed you to quickly assemble a new array based on an existing one. However, it has been removed from the standard and the Firefox implementation. Do not use it!', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions')
(42, 'Assignment operators', 'An <strong>assignment operator</strong> assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand.', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators')
(43, 'Bitwise operators', '<strong>Bitwise operators</strong> treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeroes and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal <code><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number" title="/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number">numbers</a></code>. For example, the decimal number nine has a binary representation of 1001. Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary representations, but they return standard JavaScript numerical values.', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators')
(44, 'Comma operator', 'The<strong> comma operator</strong> evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)\xa0and returns the value of the last operand.', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator')
```

This is the SQL code of the empty table I'm trying to write:

```
    CREATE TABLE `all` (
  `idall` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `desc` text NOT NULL,
  `link` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idall`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci '
```

All the columns are assigned to be not null, because I don't expect to have any nulls. I've tried, however, creating one more table 'all2' in MySQL, which is exactly the same but all 4 columns don't have the 'NOT NULL'. Still got the same error while trying to write it.

---

> **Just fixed it!**

My data is a list of articles from MDN about JavaScript. While there were no missing pieces of data, 2 out of 875 entries were named: NaN and null. In my csv file, they were not even in quotation marks, separated only by commas. I tried using str(el) before, I guess that instead of 'NaN' it produced ''. Putting '' around null solved the issue!

Comment: My guess would be that one of the integer values in your CSV file is `NaN` (not a number)

Comment: try addig a `print output` line after you assign to `output`. that should make it clear what the issue is.

Comment: I've done that!     'if name == None or desc == None or link == None: print(error)' shows no errors, and  all ids are > 0

Comment: print(output) shows nice tuples with data

Comment: Can you add your table definition and sample data as text to the question.

Comment: attached it to the post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is shown because you are sending a `NaN` value to your database. Please check the values like this.

```
import numpy as np
np.isnan(name)
```

If you actually dont care of that `NaN` values you could try doing:

```
df.fillna(0)
```

and replace the `0` with anything you like.

Comment: np.isnan() worked only for the id values, and none of them were NaN. For the string values, I got a TypeError, but anyways I checked them before with 'if name == None or desc == None or link == None' and name == '"" etc, so the data is fine

Comment: and the df.fillna(0), as well as df.fillna('string') didn't do anything for me :( Any idea what else might be causing the issue?

Comment: you could try changing the way of passing the variables:
`add_sql = ("INSERT INTO db VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})".format(str(id), name, desc, link))`

Comment: Adding the names of the names of the columns could also be something to prove. add_sql = ("INSERT INTO db (`id`, `name`, `desc`, `link`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)").  [Look here](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-insert-data-into-database-table/)